# Blackberry Application and Signing key

Tags: blackberry, key

i am Android developer, i just started to learn about Blackberry Application Development. i want to ask you something about Application and Signing keys.

I have downloaded 3 signed keys (*.csi) files. and i have installed it and added in first demo application to run app on real device. it is working and running fine in real device.

now i have created second demo application, it is also working well in simulator. but when i am trying to launch it in real device. it is loaded/installed successfully but when i am tapping on icon or trying to open application. it is not opening/running on device.

in second project, i tried by right click on project > Blackberry > Sign With Signature Tool. but it is signing only two files while in my first demo application it is signing 3 files.

also it is not generating .csl file in second application.

Please help me.. Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

Ajay, will you describe your exect problem actually no of signing the file depends how many .cod file are there in your build ( You can check it by rename your .cod file and change its extension by zip and then extract it)

for more detail regarding the BlackBerry app signing process you can follow these steps.
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/BlackBerry-Applications-and-code-signing-Start-to-Finish/ta-p/445848

Answer (score 0):

There are cod files which require signing and some others are optional. Once all the signatures are correctly added, then the *.cod and *.jad can be copied. 
Now *.cod can be extracted by renaming the same to *.zip. By extracting the zip file along with the *.jad the same can be used to download to blackberry devices. 
If this is directly uploaded to blackberry device through USB, then *.cod, *.jad and *.alx can be copied and used , no need to extract the *.cod